# angular-validator and ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I´m newbie in angular. I´m using `angular-validator` to validate the inputs in my application. I´m using `ui-select` plugin to display select list. 
I need is to validate if the user submitted a form & he didn't chosen an option in the select list then I'm gonna show required error message like the first input does in Plunkr. I believe that the validation is right but it doesn't show any error message, I've searched in the web but still no luck in R&D.

Any help would appreciated, Thanks in advance (Apologize for my Bad English)

[**Problem Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TbDVS2AmJTk8akvAY0C3?p=preview)

Comment: attached plunkr is not working

Comment: could you please make plunkr workable.

Comment: oh sorry, it was working only in chrome, i have updated the Plunkr, here is the new one: http://plnkr.co/edit/TbDVS2AmJTk8akvAY0C3?p=preview

Comment: what is you current problem, get validation working in firefox? OR you want to show validation for `ui-select` field?

Comment: i want to show validation for ui-select field

Comment: why you don't implement using your own directive?

Comment: ok, Can you help me to implement an own directive to solve this?, i´m newbie in angular.

Comment: look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/ArO0dUwd0ClVkWBm1Q7n?p=preview

Comment: thank you very much, i found a directive and now i can validate ui-select field, if anybody needs, here you can check it out: http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/ and this is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hUOx0Rc8IBsjKvpvxl0l?p=preview

Comment: cool you could add it as answer..that would help others :) or you can edit my answer tooo

Answer (score 3):

There´s one directive that solve this, here´s the code:

```
app.directive('showErrors', function($timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '^form',
  link: function (scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
    // find the text box element, which has the 'name' attribute
    var inputEl   = el[0].querySelector("[name]");
    // convert the native text box element to an angular element
    var inputNgEl = angular.element(inputEl);
    // get the name on the text box
    var inputName = inputNgEl.attr('name');

    // only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
    var blurred = false;
    inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
      blurred = true;
      el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
    });

    scope.$watch(function() {
      return formCtrl[inputName].$invalid
    }, function(invalid) {
      // we only want to toggle the has-error class after the blur
      // event or if the control becomes valid
      if (!blurred && invalid) { return }
      el.toggleClass('has-error', invalid);
    });

    scope.$on('show-errors-check-validity', function() {
      el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
    });

    scope.$on('show-errors-reset', function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        el.removeClass('has-error');
      }, 0, false);
    });
  }
}});
```

Here is the documentation: http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/ and this is an example wiht ui-select: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hUOx0Rc8IBsjKvpvxl0l?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are using form then validation tracking would easy in AngularJS by playing form variable. Do mention element of form as required and get error by doing like `formName.attributeName.$error.required`

Question isn't clear so there might be 2 ways can solve your problem.

1. In `ui-select` when you use single select box at that time put required attribute on that select element, form will automatically gets invalid if you don't provide value for `ui-select`
2. If you are using multiple select then the required attribute on element level won't help you ([Github issue link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/258)). For solving this issue you need to add one directive that will provide validation of `required`

**Directive**

```
module.directive('uiSelectRequired', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return modelValue && modelValue.length;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vGY70qhMLlpX8mGvHBRP?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: ok, thanks, i´m usign a single select box, and i mentioned, i think the validation is working, you can´t submit the form if you has not selected an element in the select box, but i don´t know how to show the required message like the first input is showing in the Plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will be helpful for you:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3" style="margin-left:50px" ng-class="{'has-error': datosDeUbicacion.$submitted && datosDeUbicacion.viviendas.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="tipoViviendas">TIPO DE VIVIENDA</label>
        <ui-select name="viviendas" ng-model="viviendas.selected" class="form-control" theme="select2" reset-search-input="true" required>
          <ui-select-match placeholder="Selecciona">{{$select.selected.nombre}}</ui-select-match>
          <ui-select-choices repeat="item in tipoViviendas | filter: $select.search">
            <div ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
        <div ng-if="datosDeUbicacion.$submitted && datosDeUbicacion.viviendas.$error.required" class="help-block">
                   <div>This is required</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1YzCCC0llH3Hq4P6ZY0H?p=preview)